# Does python have template equivalent method like C++?

Tags: python, c++, generics

**Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my question? I think I express my question clearly and a lot of people seem to understand my question.**

I have a function that can apply to multiple situation.
For example, I have a function f that contains another function h, which can apply different function depend on the situation.

```
def f(n):
    return n.cost + h(n)
```

and the h function will **be determine before runtime**.

I understand that I could just use `f(n, h)` to pass in different function, but that would mess up the parameter list, which I need it to stay only one parameter.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve something like this in Python:

```
def f<h>(n):
    return n.cost + h(n)
```

as in C++:

```
template<int (*H)>
int f(Node n)
{
    return n.cost + H(n);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why not `def f_h(n):`?

Comment: @Osyotr Then I will need multiple functions, I am trying to avoid that

Comment: `functools.partial`

Comment: Pass `(n, h)` as a `tuple` and your function signature will remain a single parameter. That'll break any existing calls to `f` but something in the system has to give to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Woodford Thanks for replying but this will mess up the parameter of f though

Comment: A tuple (alternatively, a list) is a single value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a decorator function

```
def f_decorator(h):
    def f(n):
        return n.cost + h(n)
    return f

def h(n):
    return n**2

f = f_decorator(h)

print(f(2))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I'm looking for~

Comment: @Ben that's normal Because its is duplicated question

Comment: Really? Because I cannot find any similar question online. That's the reason I asked.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C++, which compiles functions into machine codes at fixed addresses before runtime, all functions in Python are objects created at runtime so there is no such thing as "`h` function will be determine (sic) *before* runtime" in Python.

If `h` isn't going to change after initialization at runtime, and you want the caller of `f` to call it with one argument, it is generally more Pythonic to make `h` the default value of an optional parameter of `f`:

```
def h(n):
    return n + 1

def f(n, h=h):
    return 2 * n + h(n)

print(f(3))
```

This outputs: `10` (`2 * 3 + 3 + 1 == 10`)